# Unity3d BootCamp Tutorial UnityScript Array Order Anomaly in ImageEffectsOrder.js

Tags: android, arrays, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am new to **Unity** and grabbed the **BootCamp project** and ran it within `Unity 4.1.5f1` as a Windows Build without any modification

I then tried to build to Android and had a bunch of errors (mostly variables not being declared)

But I have one remaining that I just don't understand...

In the following code in the file ImageEffectsOrder.js the javascript references an order method of the array `sorted[] as sorted[i].order`

The compiler errors with 'order' is not a member of object.

So I'm a little confused as to why the windows build supports this member but not android.
This makes me wonder what other surprises await when converting from platform to platform.

But for now can anyone point me to a workaround for the order member?  And I'm not quite clear on what it is actually returning...it seems the variable `i` should give you the order.

The order just seems intrinsic from the code, it is never set to any value, so what 'order' is it?  I can't seem to find any docs on this '**member**' of the Array class.

Here is the code:

```
var sorted : Array = new Array();

var i : int = 0;
for (var fx : PostEffectsBase in GetComponents(PostEffectsBase)) 
{
    if(fx && fx.enabled) 
    {   
        sorted[i++] = fx;
    }
}   


while (sorted.length) 
{
    var indexToUse : int = 0;
    var orderValue : int = -1;
    for(i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
        if(sorted[i].order > orderValue) {
        orderValue = sorted[i].order;   
        indexToUse = i;
    }
}

 ...more code...
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The problem is not with the Array Class as the `fx` that is being assigned to the `sorted[]` array is an object of class `PostEffectsBase`.

So the actual problem is one of casting when we try to use `sorted[i].order`

I changed the reference from `sorted[i].order` to `(sorted[i] as PostEffectsBase).order` and it worked.

I have to remember this. It seems there are a lot of these casts that have to be done between platforms.